# Unwanted white space on the top and left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image under a title on the top left but the image doesn't want to cover the left side.

I changed the position to position: absolute, made the margin and padding 0, inspected the HTML page and can't see anything that can influence this image.

The HTML:

```
        <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Dillan Robbertze<h1>
                        <img src="mountain-og.jpeg">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.header img{
    height:Auto;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100vw;
    z-index:1;
    }
```

Expected Results: Image is under the title top left.
Actual Results: There is a white space left and top of the image.

EDIT: I added top:0; thanks to @Somesh Mukherjee. The image moved up, but there is still a left space that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @j08691 thanks for notifying me. Can you please help to identify what typo is there with the height? The other one I saw, thanks.

Comment: @j08691 oh wow I didn't know that! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class to the parent div element. and add position relative to it.

```
.myNewClass {
    position: relative;
}
```

also, make sure your parent elements don't have margin and padding. for that, you can use a CSS reset like this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

though this will make sure all of your elements don't have any margin or padding so you need to specify all you need by yourself. you should put this at the top of your CSS file if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the top attribute

```
.header img{
    height:auto;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin:0:
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100vw;
}
```

Comment: Without having the image and seeing the page, it's hard to say. The image could have a white margin. Is the problem that there is more space between the h1 and the image than you want?

Comment: No, the image isn't supposed to have a white margin.The problem is that there is a margin or padding on the left side which shouldn't be there. I inspected it and it comes up with nothing. @user8356

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try:

> top: -28px;
>       position:relative;

Helped me once, or twice in similar situations.